# Relation between two norms in the space of bounded analytic functions on $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk. Consider $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ and $H(\mathbb{D})$. We say that a sequence in $H(\mathbb{D})$ converges to a function in $H(\mathbb{D})$ if the sequence converges to that function in every compact sunset of $\mathbb{D}$. Now let $\{f_n:n\geq 1\}$ be an uniformly bounded sequence in $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$. So, by a normal family argument there is an $u\in H(\mathbb{D})$ such that $f_n\rightarrow u$ in $H(\mathbb{D})$. Clearly $u\in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$.

Now my question is whether $f_n\rightarrow u$ in $H^\infty (\mathbb{D})$, i.e., whether $f_n\rightarrow u$ in $sup$-norm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $f_n(z) = z^n$ on the unit disk.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think about this sequence.